# Where can I farm Titanite shards?

Tags: dark-souls-2

Where is the best place to farm for titanite shards?
I am trying to upgrade my gear and I cannot find any shards I have bought everyone I could already.

Answer (score 4):

Titanite Shards can be looted from the large, green Steelworker Undead at lower Earthen Peak, as well from as the peasant villagers in upper Brightstone Cove Tseldora. Also, one skeleton warrior in Harvest Valley, resting his bones in the same cave as Gavlan, has a very high drop rate for titanite shards. Once you have cleared Iron Keep, Stone Trader Chloanne will sell an unlimited number of Titanite Shards for 1,000 souls each.

[Source](https://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Titanite+Farming)